# Cordova won't install on Mac

Tags: macos, cordova

I am trying to re-install Cordova after having removed it.
The only instructions I can find are using npm (`npm install -g cordova`), however when I do that it appears to work, but `cordova` is not available after the install has completed.

```sh
    :~ me$ npm install -g cordova
    /Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v8.14.0/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/bin/cordova -> /Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v8.14.0/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
    + cordova@9.0.0
    updated 1 package in 8.043s
    :~ me$ cordova
    -bash: cordova: command not found
```

`which terminal` returns nothing

I've also tried opening another terminal window just to check.
And reinstalled npm.

Can anyone point me to any other steps/instructions for installing Cordova on a Mac (or diagnosing failure) ?

Comment: In the [official documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova), it requires `sudo` to install `cordova` in Mac

Answer (score 0):

After having removed cordova fully by :
(1) finding it using `find / 2> /dev/null | grep -i cordova` and then
(2) doing a `rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova`

And removing it from some other places -- I was able to identify some of the other files created by the output of the install cordova command.

The install eventually gave me the latest (9.0.0) version I wanted, but it didn't create the `cordova` on the command line.

To do that I just created a manual alias by adding `cordova="/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v8.14.0/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/bin/cordova"` to my `~/.bash_profile`